# Phpunit command is showing error in laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am stuck with an issue in which i cant run my test cases. I have a laravel project where I wrote the test cases and tried to run from my homestead server.
but it shows error.

> " vendor/bin/phpunit: line 1: ../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit: No such file
>   or directory"

I have phpunit in my vendor file.

Anyone else has faced such issue, Why this error is showing up?

Waiting for a response..

Comment: can please show me your `vendor/bin/phpunit` file code

Comment: Can you write what you did to run phpunit?

Comment: vendor/bin/phpunit file contains   " ../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit ". Only this single line

Comment: I wanted to run all my unit cases, so just used phpunit command in the command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have the wrong configuration in `vendor/bin/phpunit` file

First of all, I suggest delete **phpunit** file under in `vendor/bin/phpunit`

After, in your `composer.json` file add this:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.0"
},
```

After, run this command on your command prompt: `composer update`

They will create a new **phpunit** file and all related configurations, here the `vendor/bin/phpunit` will be placed

Answer (score 0):

Try below command in command line-

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

This will load your phpunit.xml file. Otherwise it cannot load your configuration file. Unless if you don't give spesific path:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration /path/to/laravels/phpunit.xml
```